# php syntax for if statement with multiple conditions ( `||` as well as `&&` )

Tags: php, if-statement, syntax, operators, multiple-conditions

Context: On our website, we calculate whether an item/order meets the criteria for free shipping using an if statement evaluating if a value - 'ff' - is true. Depending on conditions met it sets the shipping appropriately. We now require the need to evaluate if an item is free shipping with the order of *_*. To top it off, for other purposes such as external feeds, another condition must apply (weight must = 0 or have no value), for fw to be free freight. Here is the code, that I can't figure out why it is NOT working:

```
if($r['freeFreight'] == 'ff' || ($r['freeFreight'] == 'fw' && ($r['weight'] == 0 || $r['weight'] == '') ) ) {
    $r['shippingStandard'] = 0;
}
```

Are the conditions overly segregated in the if statement with the sets of ()? Or, are they just incorrectly placed. For example, should it be:

```
if(($r['freeFreight'] == 'ff') || ($r['freeFreight'] == 'fw' && $r['weight'] == 0 || $r['weight'] == '') ) {
    $r['shippingStandard'] = 0;                     
}
```

The second of the two seems more logical to me because: if ($r['freeFreight'] == 'ff') - then regardless of the following conditions the statement should return true and set the variable to 0. Is my logic correct? Sorry for this newb question...

Thanks for any help you can offer.

---

So I think perhaps, based on the answers so far (thanks everybody that has chimed in to help an amateur) - I think I am going to do a trial with:

```
if( ($r['freeFreight'] == 'ff') || ( $r['freeFreight'] == 'fw' ) && empty( $r['weight'] ) ) { 
    $r['shippingStandard'] = 0;
}
```

Planning to run trial with this, if it is fundamentally wrong, please advise.

Comment: Are you checking `isset($r['weight'])` ?

Comment: I'm not.. smh - so would it than be 
    if(($r['freeFreight'] == 'ff') || (isset($r['weight'] && $r['freeFreight'] == 'fw' && $r['weight'] == 0 || $r['weight'] == '') ) {        $r['shippingStandard'] = 0;                     
}

Comment: `emtpy` would be cleaner than doing all those checks

Comment: try to never rely on a language's operator precedence rules if you can at all help it, and especially if you're working with multiple languages. it may be a bit more tedious, but always use proper bracketing to enforce "your" rules, instead of hoping the language parsing will do it properly for you.

Comment: @MarcB, good tip. JamesLee: I'd go with Ascherer's answer.

Comment: @MarcB - I agree, great tip. It provides peace of mind that I'm not over-bracketing (but more likely that I'm just not bracketing correctly, lol)

Comment: @klugerama - Agreed, I am just tweaking it slightly as to bracket the first condition so it will be evaluated on it's own regard, without the rest of the statement.

Comment: you dont need to put parens around the ff piece. Its going to be seen as the first operator, and if its true, the if will end right there

Comment: @Ascherer you have been very very helpful. I'm going with exactly what you recommended in your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out?

```
if( $r['freeFreight'] == 'ff' || ( $r[ 'freeFreight' ] == 'fw' && empty( $r['weight'] ) ) ) {
    $r['shippingStandard'] = 0;
}
```

using `empty` might be a little cleaner too

if you really want to break it out more, you could do this

```
if( $r[ 'freeFreight' ] == 'ff' ) {
    $r[ 'shippingStandard' ] = 0;
} elseif( $r[ 'freeFreight' ] == 'fw' && empty( $r[ 'weight' ] ) ) {
    $r[ 'shippingStandard' ] = 0;
} else {
    // Everything else
}
```

If you want to shorten the variables, and will be using them later:

```
$freight  = $r[ 'freeFreight' ];
$weight   = isset( $r[ 'weight' ] ) ? $r[ 'weight' ] : null;
$shipping = $r[ 'shippingStandard' ]; // Or whatever you want the default value to be...
if( $freight == 'ff' || ( $freight == 'fw' && empty( $weight ) ) ) {
    $shipping = 0;
}

// ... Later down the file
$r = array( 
    'freeFreight' => $freight,
    'weight' => $weight, 
    'shippingStandard' => $shipping
);
```

I really cant tell how the rest of the file looks, like if this is in a function to get shipping, you could simply just return `$shipping`. Hope this helps. You should be able to move the concepts around to get what you want

Comment: The problem is, if $r['freeFreight'] == 'ff' we don't care whether $r['weight'] = null, '', 0, or 9081239082. Should this just be done with an if else statement?

Comment: I think this is I'm going to give the empty a shot, but bracket off the first condition. It may be exactly what we're looking for.

Comment: yeah, i fixed that so it was what you wanted. You could clean it up more, by assigning `$r['freeFreight']` to `$freight`, so it fits better on the line, idk if you will use that variable later in the function

Comment: added another edit, @JamesLee if you wanted to break it out this way

Comment: @JamesLee try leaving comments rather than editing the answer, these will just be rejected as invalid, attempt to comment or reply"

Comment: @Deanna - Thank you. Sorry about that I was unsure about that. This is my first time actually posting anything on stackoverflow.com - although I've researched many things here, and it is a great resource to have. Our Lead Developer is no longer with the company, and since I have moderate knowledge of PHP, I've kind of assumed the interim role. (I'm actually in marketing, but I did formerly write a lot of js/jquery for this site. I will try to use proper etiquette with regards to comments/edits/posts and so forth. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

your first option should should be identical to the following:

```
if ($r['freeFreight'] == 'ff') {
    $r['shippingStandard'] = 0;
}
elseif ($r['freeFreight'] == 'fw') {
    // the dual check for an empty value here is kind of redundant and unneccessary.
    // I'd probably just use "if ($r['weight'])" and be done with it
    if ($r['weight'] == 0) {
        $r['shippingStandard'] = 0;
    }
    elseif ($r['weight'] == '') {
        $r['shippingStandard'] = 0;
    }
    else {
        // $r['shippingStandard'] stays whatever it was before
    }
}
else {
    // $r['shippingStandard'] stays whatever it was before
}
```

if that logic looks right to you, then you should be right on and I'd `print_r($r)` to make sure it's holding what you expect it to be holding.  Your parenthesis in the first example is exactly how I would do it.

Comment: `if( $r[ 'weight' ] )` is a very lazy check, and doesn't leave much to saying what you are checking for. PLEASE use something like `empty` to say exactly what you are looking for. Just because PHP lets you hang yourself with code, it doesn't mean you should. `if( empty( $r[ 'weight' ] ) )` checks for null, set, 0, and ''

Comment: @Ascherer Awesome! I was not aware `empty` checked for 0, that's great! I can knock off the last part of my if statement I just added to my OP.

Comment: Normally I'm on the "explicit intentions" bandwagon, and I might come around on `empty()` eventually, but all it does is evaluate to true when the supplied variable implicitly evaluates to false... I try to eliminate cruft where I can, and I haven't gotten over the crufty feeling of `empty()`.  What it does do is allow me not to care about the existence of the variable, which I feel I either should know, or check more explicitly with `isset()`.  At any rate, just know it's a style choice I've thus far made on purpose.